# c# Smartsheet API: Can Not Get ColumnId

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I am trying to read data from Smartsheet using C# SDK. I can get sheet info but column details such as ColumnId are Null.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Smartsheet.Api;
using Smartsheet.Api.Models;
using Smartsheet.Api.OAuth;

namespace SmartSheetTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string token = "MY_TOKEN";
            long sheetid = MY_SHEET_ID;

            SmartsheetClient sc = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(token).Build();

            Sheet sheet = sc.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetid, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is below. Only column type and title is filled. Other properties are Null

[image: ColumnId Null]

How can I get column properties?

SDK Version : 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Each column within the `sheet` object that's populated by the `GetSheet` response should always contain a value for the following properties, at a minimum:

- **Id**
- **Index**
- **Title**
- **Type**
- **Width**

It's entirely possible that some of the other properties you're seeing in Debug mode might be `null` by design, BUT each and every `column` in the response should always contain an `Id` property value that you could subsequently use in a `GetColumn` request to retrieve all column property values.

I'm unable to reproduce your issue. I've used the code that you've posted (with version 2.2.1 of the Smartsheet C# SDK) to retrieve a Sheet and examine the properties of several columns within the `sheet` object that's populated by the `GetSheet` response. Regardless of which sheet I retrieve or which column I inspect in Debug mode, the properties listed above are always populated, as shown by this screenshot:

[image: Column properties]

A couple of suggestions for troubleshooting:

- Test this scenario using a different sheet. If you CANNOT repro the issue with a different sheet, then perhaps there's something particular about the one sheet that's preventing the `Id` attribute from populating in the `GetSheet` response.
- If you CAN repro this issue with another sheet, then perhaps try testing this same scenario using this sample app: https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/csharp-read-write-sheet.  Note -- you'll need to update the Smartsheet C# SDK NuGet package to version 2.2.1 to exactly mimic the scenario you're wanting to test. (I used this sample app in my (unsuccessful) attempt to repro your issue.)

Comment: Thank you @kim for your detailed answer. I have already tried your suggestions
1. Tried different sheets: Same problem
2. Tried sample application: Simply downloaded sample app and changed config and run, same promlem
3. Tried Postman: Works fine. I can see column id and all other details in json response
4. Tried Python: Works fine

This thing is surely something about Visual Studio but I can not resole it.
I decided to go on with Python.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Decoded. Sorry to hear that you couldn't get things to work with the C# SDK in Visual Studio, but glad to hear that you're able to move forward by using Python instead.

Comment: @Decoded, can you please let us know your environment? E.g. Operating system and developer tools. Your screen shot doesn't look like Visual Studio - are you using VS Code?

Comment: Hİ @Steve. It definitely is Visual studio. I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 on Win 10 Pro x64 Machine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late, but you can iterate through the columns by accessing the sheet.Columns property. I've used it to get the ColumnId and the Title, which is the header string text.

```
foreach (Column column in sheet.Columns)
        Debug.WriteLine(column.Title + " " + column.Id));
```